# how do i get an id of an element which has a class

Tags: jquery, element

Let's say i have list

```
<ul id="left-side-menu" style="display: block;">

    <li> <a id="1" class="lists active" href="javascript:void(0)">My company 1</a></li>

    <li> <a id="2" class="lists" href="javascript:void(0)">My company 2</a></li>

    <li> <a id="3" class="lists" href="javascript:void(0)">My company 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In order to get the id of an element which has active class using the lists class, i wrote like this

> $("a.lists").hasClass("active").attr('id');

but it gives an error

> $("a.lists").hasClass("active").attr is not a function

Please help me

Comment: RTFM [http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) Return value of hasClass is bolean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("a.lists.active").attr('id')
```

Comment: Thank you xdazz for the quick reply and relevant answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.lists.active").attr('id');
```

Comment: Thank you DQM for the quick reply and relevant answer

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the [`.hasClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) is a boolean, and of course a boolean doesn't have an `.attr()` method.

To select an element that has multiple classes just list all of the required classes with *no spaces* between the names, like this:

```
$("a.lists.active").attr('id');
```

That should return the value of the id of the first element to match that selector, or undefined if no elements match. (If you expect to always have exactly one element with the "active" class it will be fine.)

Comment: i'm a newbie in jquery,that's why this error occurs, thank you for your explanation. now i understand the fact