# get the id of the class which has class active?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the id of the id of the element which has class active. I've viewed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695828/how-do-i-get-an-id-of-an-element-which-has-a-class) , but isnt able to get the o/p I want.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked navigation" id="configuration_sidebar_content">
     <li>
        <a>Location</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked " id="location" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <li class="active" id="region"><a>Region</a></li>
            <li id="country"><a>Country</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a>Device</a>
         <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="padding-left:30px;">
              <li id="gateway_unit"><a>Gateway Unit</a></li>
              <li id="meter_unit"><a>Meter Unit</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I **tried** this.

```
selected_item_id = $("#configuration_sidebar_content li.a.active").attr('id')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it should be

```
$("#configuration_sidebar_content li.active").attr('id')
```

there is no class `a` assigned to the `li` element, `a` is a child element of the `li` element

Answer (score 3):

You code didn't work, because you wrote `.a`, which means *having class `a`*, which wasn't what you're looking for.
Try this:

```
  $("#configuration_sidebar_content").find(".active").attr('id')
```

Using `find()` is **more effective** than selectors with spaces inside (e.g. `li a`).

Answer (score 2):

you can also try

```
$("#configuration_sidebar_content li").find("a.active").attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , `#configuration_sidebar_content li.a.active` change to `$("#configuration_sidebar_content li.active").attr('id')`

http://jsfiddle.net/yWsRR/